# iPhone: How to implement a Persian Calendar?

Tags: iphone, database, sdk

I'm in the process of making a Persian Calendar app for Persian users. 
I was wondering if I have to make a database to store all the days or is there an algorithm to generate the calendar?

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a database (or some sort of local storage) to store the events on the calendar.  You should not need to store days without any events.  A quick Google search turned up several sites with explanations of the calendar - it looks like a very straightforward algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The [NSLocale class](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a NSPersianCalendar key you can use to generate a Persian calendar with NSCalendar. It says it is supported in 10.6 but doesn't mention iPhone so it might not be available.

In any case, make sure you use a tested algorithm developed by specialist. Calendar calculations are deceptively complex and error prone.